# SQL CASE Clauses with variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near '='.

Code:

```
WHERE 
     T.[ID] = -9769 
     AND TNS.Active = 1
     AND CASE   
            WHEN T.[StatusID] IN (1,6) 
              THEN (T.[AuditUser_ID] = 2  AND TNX.Actor = 2)
         END
```

Comment: `CASE   
WHEN T.[StatusID] IN (1,6) THEN
    (T.[AuditUser_ID] = 2  AND TNX.Actor = 2)
END` What exactly is this supposed to mean?

Comment: `CASE` is an **expression** that returns one value (from multiple possible values) - it cannot however return blocks of code to use in your `WHERE` clause ....

Comment: Where is this CASE expression using a variable, and what are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE 
     T.[ID] = -9769 
     AND TNS.Active = 1
     AND 1 = CASE   
             WHEN T.[StatusID] IN (1,6) 
             and (T.[AuditUser_ID] = 2  AND TNX.Actor = 2) then 1 else 0
         END
```

Comment: why are you using a case expression ? You can remove the case and use *AND* instead